# Is it possible to compile test binary using `go install` instead of `go test -c`

Tags: go, build

I would like to build test binary whenever it is need (only if the package or it's dependencies changed) - something like `go install` vs `go build`.

The only option option to speed up building test binaries is `-i` (`go test -c -i`).

Any idea if this is supported by the `go` tool? Is there any other `go` like tool to do it (I would like to use a tool with native support on go packages instead of a file based system like `make`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Before go 1.10

For go < 1.10, the `go build` doesn't store the package compiled object files. The `go install` does. One solution is to call `go install` in the right package. It will go through all package dependencies, compile them if the timestamp of the file in the dependency package changed, store the object file and then link them all. 
Example:

```
GOBIN="my project build directory" go install ./cmd/mycmd
```

Another solution is to use `-i` flag, which is supported by `build` and `test` commands.

### After go 1.10

go 1.10 adds new flag to `go build` which does the "smart" caching.

> The go build command now detects out-of-date packages purely based on the content of source files, specified build flags, and metadata stored in the compiled packages. Modification times are no longer consulted or relevant. The old advice to add -a to force a rebuild in cases where the modification times were misleading for one reason or another (for example, changes in build flags) is no longer necessary: builds now always detect when packages must be rebuilt. (If you observe otherwise, please file a bug.)

Read [release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#build) for more information.